# How to import a Java program into Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, import, manifest

I have some java source code. It an just an archive which is four folders.

Folders MAIN, DATA, TAGS, USER_INTERFACE. Each folder contains a few class files.

I see how everything works together, but can't see to get the program to import correctly or run. I did find a MANIFEST.MF. 
What is the proper way to import such a project?

Comment: you can also check 'link additional source' after you get eclipse folder structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an Eclipse project. Under the project settings, select the "Java Build Path", and add each source folder (and remove the default `src` folder that Eclipse may add for you).

If necessary, you may set the output/build folders for each source directory, and clear Eclipse's default `bin` output directory. Check the "Allow output folders for source folders" to enable this, then set each source folder's output folder.

(You may or may not want to keep compiled classes in individual directories.)

If there are class files in the project that aren't generated from source in the project, in the same dialog, select the "Libraries" tab, and click the "Add Class Folder" button to add dependencies from within the project.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem that your source code is an eclipse-importable project (it would have to have a .classpath and .project file in the top level directory for that).

You should instead create a new Java project. For simplicity, set the project's location to be the parent directory of your MAIN, DATA, etc. directories. Then after the project is created, configure a source folder for each of MAIN, DATA, etc. (right-click the project, choose Properties > Java Build Path, then work in the Source tab). Your source folders should then show up in the navigator and the project should be able to be compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Create a hello world project in eclipse and understand the project structure in eclipse. 
And then manually import the files it is simple and avoids a lot of confusion especially for somebody new to the environment.